# Cant use filter function in the return statement for reactjs. Throwing error

Tags: reactjs, filter

*I'm trying to filter the data directly under the return statement*. I am getting this error "Objects are not valid as a React child. If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead". Map function works just fine. Map and Filter both return array

Here's my code

```
export class TestPage extends Component {
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
        proPlayerData: []
    }
}

componentDidMount(){
    this.fetchData();
    this.filterData();
}

filterData = () => {
}

fetchData = async() => {
    const playerData = await fetch("https://api.opendota.com/api/playersByRank");
    const player_data = await playerData.json()
    console.log("fetch",player_data);
    await this.setState({proPlayerData: [...player_data]})
}

render() {
    // let topTenIds = this.state.proPlayerData
    // console.log(topTenIds)
    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.proPlayerData.filter((data,index) => {
                if(index <= 10){
                   return <div key={index}>data.accountId</div>
                }
            })}
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

export default TestPage

Why can't I use filter just like map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Array.prototype.map` *transforms* data from one format to another, its used in react a lot to *transform* your arrays of data into `JSX`

`Array.prototype.filter` will filter data in your data arrays, but not alter the format, therefore if you start with an array of objects, you will end with an array of objects of the same shape (or an empty array if none meet the condition in the callback)

You need a combination of both, first a `filter` to filter the data you want, then a `map` to transform your filtered data into `JSX`, but even still rather than a filter, which will iterate over each element, you only need the first 10, looking at your example, therefore you can use `Array.prototype.slice` -

```
this.state.proPlayerData
   .slice(0, 10)
   .map((data) => (<div key={index}>{data.accountId}</div>))
```

edit... looks like you maybe want to the first 11, therefore update the slice args to suit...